# 動画を表示するプログラムを動かそうとしていますが、動画をどこに置けばよろしいでしょうか

Tags: objective-c, xcode

iOSアプリ開発の初心者です。

XcodeとObjective-Cを使って動画を表示するサンプルを動かそうとしていますが、動画が表示されません。
動画のパスの部分のコードは

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResourse:@"sample" ofType:@"move"];
```

となっています。

説明には｢リソースから読み込む｣と書いてあったのですが、このリソースというのが何を指しているのかよく分かりません。
動画をxcodeprojファイルと同じ階層に置いたり、ソースファイルがあるフォルダに入れたりしてみましたが、表示されません。動画をどこに置けばよいのでしょうか。

初歩的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、これに関して説明されている情報が見つからないので、よろしければご返答よろしくお願いします。

Comment: `ofType:@"move"`の`move`は、`mov`の間違いではありませんか？

Answer (score 3):

> 説明には｢リソースから読み込む｣と書いてあったのですが、このリソースというのが何を指しているのかよく分かりません。

リソース（Resource）は、プログラムコード以外のアプリケーションの構成物のことです（アプリケーション限定ではなく、プラグインや機能拡張などにも使います）。
画像や音声ファイル、アイコンデータや、Storyboard、XIBファイルもリソースです。
プロジェクトにリソースとなるファイルを加えるのは、かんたんです。Xcodeの**Project Navigator**へ、Finderウインドウからドラッグ＆ドロップします。
（Finder上で、直接プロジェクトフォルダに移動しても、Xcodeとプロジェクトは、追加されたことを認識できません）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

プロジェクトに追加したリソースは、ビルド時、Xcodeがアプリのパッケージにコピーしてくれますから、プログラマが直接作業することはありません。

リソース追加時に気をつけたいのが、リソースが有効になっているかどうか、確認することです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

リソース追加時に上図のダイアログが出ますが、赤線箇所のチェックが入っていないとEnable（有効）にならず、「見つからない」とビルド後にXcodeから注意されます。（これは、動画候補A、動画候補Bを切り替えて、動作テストする、みたいなケースを考えているものと思われます）